# С заглавной ли буквы пишутся названия вымышленных существ?

Tags: грамматика

Прочитав [Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации (1956 г.)](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/139-prop) п.96-99, я так и не смог понять, следует ли писать с заглавной буквы выдуманные автором названия существ или рас. Например, если взять зергов из игры Warhammer, то по-русски они должны быть Зерги или зерги? Я склоняюсь к написанию с прописной буквы, но не уверен.

Comment: смотря, конечно, из какой вселенной, если из Вархаммера, то Дитмар Эльяшевич сказал, что надо "зерги" писать с маленькой, а если из Старкрафта, то, конечно, с большой!

Comment: Со строчной они пишутся. С прописной пишется то, что является личным, индивидуальным именем, названия видов – со строчной. Там в правилах всё чётко разъясняется.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE! This chapter in the rulebook is titled *Прописные буквы*, which implies that by default, unless explicitly covered by some rule in this chapter, all words should start with the lowercase. This is quite a bold assumption for a style guide book, but here we are. When you're saying that "you're not sure", do you have some particular rule in mind which you don't know how to interpret, or are you not convinced that this rule set is exhaustive and covers all possible cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, answering your direct question: I personally think that yes, you should spell *зерги* with the lowercase, by analogy with the names of Earth animals, nations and races: *волки, овцы; китайцы, русские; негры, индейцы* etc.

The problem with applying this rule book is deciding whether or not we subscribe to the unwritten assumption that the rule set it provides is exhaustive, and everything which is not explicitly covered by this chapter is by default lowercase.

If we do subscribe to this point of view, then the names of animals and races are not covered by any rule in this chapter, and we should write it in lowercase.

This point of view, though, contradicts the real usage in lots of edge cases.

For instance, biological family names start with lowercase when used in genitive: *волк — представитель семейства псовых*. But the usage varies when talking about the name of the family: *семейство Псовые / псовые, к которому принадлежит волк*. You can see both variants in actual usage.

I would not go so far as to claim the variant with the capital is wrong just because it's not covered by this rule book.

If we don't subscribe to this point of view, then the answer is "we don't know, we should seek advice elsewhere", because fictional races are not explicitly covered by the rule book.

But again, real-world races and nations are a very strong analogy, and they are written with the lowercase.

Comment: `But again, real-world races and nations are a very strong analogy, and they are written with the lowercase.` that's probably where the question came from, most of languages do capitalize those. Starcraft lore capitalizes Terrans, Zergs and Protoss as nations in original text, per English language ruling. Localizations of game made that mistake and capitalized them in translation.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала тут просто не важно, вымышленные они или нет (вы же как бы погружаетесь в данную вымышленную Вселенную и принимаете её "реалии"), речь просто идет о названии индивидов(!) вида, либо,если хотите,народа;
В обычных ситуациях подобные названия пишутся со строчной буквы.

Как тут выше сказали, в случае, если речь идет о названии вида именно в биологической систематике - то оно довольно часто пишется с прописной буквы, как именно название вида (и не только семейств и т.д., но и вида), а не индивида(!) вида; но это бы звучало как,например, "Зерг обыкновенный" (Zerg vulgaris), и в именительном падеже (дело в том, что тут фокус не на каких-либо объектах, вид это же абстракция - а на именно названии вида).
Но тут речь именно лишь о биологической систематике. Например, это могло бы встретится в каком-нибудь ксенологическом справочнике,но не в каком-либо ином стиле и случае.

Иногда встречается еще один момент (и, мне кажется, от конкретного языка это не зависит) - если вы хотите подчеркнуть некий эмоциональный накал, пафос, cтрах или нечто подобное, связанное с этими существами (или любыми иными субъектами-объектами),- ваш накал или какого-либо персонажа этой Вселенной :
"...да придут Зерги !"
"...воздвигайте стены, иначе придут Зерги !"  - тогда именно подобное отношение к ним может быть выделено с помощью прописной буквы.
Это,конечно,специфический случай. Некоторым образом это схоже по смыслу с п. 95.3.(прим. о прописных), 95.7 ,98, 102, 103, 104, 109("Человек") на вашей ссылке.